# C++ code stops mid-compiling with error segmentation fault

Tags: c++, c++11, neural-network, mnist

I'm working on a Neural Network for classifying handwriten number (MNIST). Im using Mingw-w64 (c++ 11) on a windows 10 device. Im using Sublime Text 3 with the default build system provided by Sublime Text. In my program i have this function called run (which is supoused to run for 500 iterations) but after around 400 iterations I get segmentation fault in the funcion called addVectors (I am pretty sure the cause of the segmentation fault is my computer running out of memory), so then my question is how can I reduce memroy consumption. I'm pretty new to programming so all "tips and tricks", and ideas will be greatfully recived. Code is inspirred by (https://www.kaggle.com/wwsalmon/simple-mnist-nn-from-scratch-numpy-no-tf-keras/notebook), the dataset is also on the same site. Please help.

```
#include "matrixLibrary.h"

#define swap16(n) (((n&0xFF00)>>8)|((n&0x00FF)<<8))
#define swap32(n) ((swap16((n&0xFFFF0000)>>16))|((swap16(n&0x0000FFFF))<<16))

typedef unsigned char byte;

struct MNISTchar {
    std::vector<float> pixelData;
    std::vector<float> output;
    int label;
    MNISTchar() : pixelData(std::vector<float>()), output(std::vector<float>(10)), label(0) {}
};


class MNIST{
public:
    //MNIST loader by Peter Baumann (https://github.com/krck/MNIST-Loader) 
    const std::vector<MNISTchar> trainingData;
    const std::vector<MNISTchar> testData;
    
    MNIST(const std::string& path, int maxNumb)
    : trainingData(getMNISTdata(path + "train-images-idx3-ubyte", path + "train-labels-idx1-ubyte")),
        testData(getMNISTdata(path + "t10k-images-idx3-ubyte", path + "t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte")) {
            if(!this->trainingData.size()) { std::cout <<"ERROR: parsing training data" <<std::endl; }
            if(!this->testData.size()) { std::cout <<"ERROR: parsing testing data" <<std::endl; }
    }   

private:
    std::vector<MNISTchar> getMNISTdata(const std::string& imagepath, const std::string& labelpath) {
        std::vector<MNISTchar> tmpdata = std::vector<MNISTchar>();
        std::fstream file (imagepath, std::ifstream::in | std::ifstream::binary);
        int magicNum_images = 0, magicNum_labels = 0;
        int itemCount_images = 0, itemCount_labels = 0;
        if(file.is_open()) {
            int row_count = 0, col_count = 0;
            file.read((char*)&magicNum_images, 4);
            file.read((char*)&itemCount_images, 4);
            file.read((char*)&row_count, 4);
            file.read((char*)&col_count, 4);
            magicNum_images = swap32(magicNum_images);
            itemCount_images = swap32(itemCount_images);
            row_count = swap32(row_count);
            col_count= swap32(col_count);
            for (int i = 0; i < itemCount_images; i++) {
                MNISTchar tmpchar = MNISTchar();
                for(int r = 0; r < (row_count * col_count); r++) {
                    byte pixel = 0;
                    file.read((char*)&pixel, 1);
                    tmpchar.pixelData.push_back((float)pixel / 255);
                }
                tmpdata.push_back(tmpchar);
            }
        }
        file.close();
        file.open(labelpath, std::ifstream::in | std::ifstream::binary);
        if (file.is_open()) {
            file.read((char*)&magicNum_labels, 4);
            file.read((char*)&itemCount_labels, 4);
            magicNum_labels = swap32(magicNum_labels);
            itemCount_labels = swap32(itemCount_labels);
            if(itemCount_images == itemCount_labels) {
                for(MNISTchar& m : tmpdata) {
                    file.read((char*)&m.label, 1);
                    m.output[m.label] = 1.0f;
                }
            }
        }
        file.close();
        return tmpdata;
    }


public:
    void run(float minNumb, float maxNumb, float learningrate, short itereations){
        Helpers helpers = Helpers();

        short inputSize = 784;
        short dimension1 = 10;
        short outputSize = 10;


        matrixF* weights1 = helpers.initializeWeight(dimension1, inputSize, minNumb, maxNumb);
        matrixF* weights2 = helpers.initializeWeight(outputSize, dimension1, minNumb, maxNumb);

        vecF* bias1 = helpers.initializeBias(dimension1, minNumb, maxNumb);
        vecF* bias2 = helpers.initializeBias(outputSize, minNumb, maxNumb);

        matrixF* input = new matrixF(batchSize, vecF(inputSize));
        input->clear();
        matrixF* correctOutput = new matrixF(batchSize, vecF(outputSize));
        correctOutput->clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < batchSize; i++){
            input->push_back(trainingData[i].pixelData);
            correctOutput->push_back(trainingData[i].output);
        }

        input = helpers.transform(input);
        correctOutput = helpers.transform(correctOutput);

        matrixF* wbOut1 = 0;
        matrixF* wbOut2 = 0;

        matrixF* actFuncOut1 = 0;
        matrixF* actFuncOut2 = 0;

        float append = learningrate/batchSize;
        matrixF* dOut1 = new matrixF(batchSize, vecF(dimension1));

        for (short i = 0; i < itereations; i++){
            wbOut1 = helpers.forwardProp2(weights1, helpers.transform(input), bias1, batchSize, dimension1);
            actFuncOut1 = helpers.reLUMatrix(wbOut1);
            wbOut2 = helpers.forwardProp2(weights2, helpers.transform(actFuncOut1), bias2, batchSize, outputSize);
            actFuncOut2 = helpers.reLUMatrix(wbOut2);

            //backprop start
            matrixF* dOut2 = 0;
            dOut1->clear();

            dOut2 = helpers.subtractMatrices(actFuncOut2, correctOutput);

            helpers.outDeriv(dOut1, helpers.transform(weights2), helpers.transform(dOut2), wbOut1, dimension1);

            weights1 = helpers.subtractMatrices(weights1, helpers.fullDot(dOut1, input, dimension1, inputSize, append));
            bias1 = helpers.subtractVectors(bias1, helpers.sumMatrix(dOut1, append), dimension1);

            weights2 = helpers.subtractMatrices(weights2, helpers.fullDot(dOut2, actFuncOut1, dimension1, outputSize, append));
            bias2 = helpers.subtractVectors(bias2, helpers.sumMatrix(dOut2, append), outputSize);
            //backprop done
            std::cout<<i+1<<std::endl;

            helpers.getAccuracy(helpers.transform(actFuncOut2), helpers.transform(correctOutput));
            helpers.checkMemory(0);
        }
    }
};

typedef std::chrono::steady_clock clk;

int main(){
    const clk::time_point startTime = clk::now();
    MNIST mnist = MNIST("Dataset/", 1);
    const clk::time_point stopLoad = clk::now();
    float time = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(stopLoad - startTime).count();
    std::cout<<"Load time: "<<time/1000<<" sec." <<std::endl;

    std::srand(std::time(nullptr));
    mnist.run(-0.5, 1, 0.01, 500);
    
    const clk::time_point stopTotal = clk::now();
    time = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(stopTotal - startTime).count();
    std::cout<<"Total compile time: "<<time/1000<<" sec." <<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

```
#include"matrixLibrary.h"

Helpers::Helpers(){

}

Helpers::~Helpers(){

}

short Helpers::getSizeMat(matrixF* mat){
    short i = 0;
    for (vecF vec : *mat){
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}

short Helpers::getSizeVec(vecF* vec){
    short i = 0;
    for (float f : *vec){
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}

float Helpers::randNumb(float minNumb, float maxNumb){
    return minNumb + static_cast <float> (rand()) /( static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX/(maxNumb-minNumb)));
}

float Helpers::reLU(float numb){
    return (numb > 0) ? numb : 0;
}

float Helpers::reLUDeriv(float numb){
    return numb > 0;
}

matrixF* Helpers::reLUMatrix(matrixF* input){
    short i = getSizeMat(input);
    short j = getSizeVec(&(*input)[0]);
    matrixF* result = new matrixF(i, vecF(j));
    vecF* oneVec = new vecF(j);
    result->clear();
    for (vecF vec : *input){
        oneVec->clear();
        for (float f : vec){
            oneVec->push_back(reLU(f));
        }
        result->push_back(*oneVec);
    }
    return result;
}

float Helpers::sigmoid(float numb){
    return 1/(1+exp(-numb));
}

float Helpers::sigmoidDeriv(float numb){
    return exp(-numb)/pow((1+exp(-numb)), 2);
}

float Helpers::sigmoidInverse(float numb){
    return log(1/numb-1)/-1;
}

matrixF* Helpers::sigmoidMatrix(matrixF* input){
    short i = getSizeMat(input);
    short j = getSizeVec(&(*input)[0]);
    matrixF* result = new matrixF(i, vecF(j));
    vecF* oneVec = new vecF(j);
    result->clear();
    for (vecF vec : *input){
        oneVec->clear();
        for (float f : vec){
            oneVec->push_back(sigmoid(f));
        }
        result->push_back(*oneVec);
    }
    return result;
}

float Helpers::dotProduct(vecF* vector1, vecF* vector2) {
    float product = 0.0;
    short i = 0;
    for (float elem : *vector1){
        product += elem * (*vector2)[i];
        i++;
    }
    return product;
}

matrixF* Helpers::fullDot(matrixF* input1, matrixF* input2, short size1, short size2, float append){
    matrixF* result = new matrixF(size1, vecF(size2));
    vecF* oneVec = new vecF(size2);
    result->clear();
    for (vecF vec1 : *input1){
        oneVec->clear();
        for (vecF vec2 : *input2){
            oneVec->push_back(dotProduct(&vec1, &vec2) * append);
        }
        result->push_back(*oneVec);
    }
    return result;
}

void Helpers::outDeriv(matrixF* outMat, matrixF* input1, matrixF* input2, matrixF* input3, short size){
    vecF* oneVec = new vecF(size);
    short i = 0, j = 0;
    for (vecF vec : *input1){
        oneVec->clear();
        j = 0;
        for (vecF weight : *input2){
            oneVec->push_back(dotProduct(&weight, &vec) * reLUDeriv((*input3)[i][j]));
            j++;
        }
        outMat->push_back(*oneVec);
        i++;
    }
}

void Helpers::addVectors(vecF* vec1, vecF* vec2){
    short i = 0;
    for (float f : *vec1){
        (*vec1)[i] = f + (*vec2)[i];
        i++;
    }
}

void Helpers::addBias(matrixF* input, vecF* bias){
    short i = 0;
    for (vecF vec : *input){
        addVectors(&vec, bias);
        (*input)[i].assign(vec.begin(), vec.end());
        i++;
    }
}

matrixF* Helpers::forwardProp1(matrixF* input, matrixF* weights, vecF* bias, short size){
    matrixF* result = new matrixF();
    vecF* oneImg = new vecF(size);
    result->clear();
    short int i = 0;
    for (vecF image : *input){
        oneImg->clear();
        for (vecF weight : *weights){
            oneImg->push_back(sigmoid(dotProduct(&weight, &image) + (*bias)[i]));
        }
        result->push_back(*oneImg);
        i+=1;
    }
    return result;
}

matrixF* Helpers::forwardProp2(matrixF* input, matrixF* weights, vecF* bias, short size1, short size2){    
    matrixF* temp = 0;
    temp = fullDot(input, weights, size1, size2, 1);
    addBias(temp, bias);
    return temp;
}

float Helpers::squareError(vecF* output, vecF* correctOutput, short size){
    float gradient = 0.0;
    for (short int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        gradient += pow((*output)[i] - (*correctOutput)[i], 2);
    }
    return gradient;
}

vecF* Helpers::sumMatrix(matrixF* input, float append){
    vecF* result = new vecF(getSizeVec(&(*input)[0]));
    float tempf;
    result->clear();
    for (vecF vec : *input){
        tempf = 0;
        for (float f : vec){
            tempf += f * append;
        }
        result->push_back(tempf);
    }
    return result;
}

matrixF* Helpers::subtractMatrices(matrixF* mat1, matrixF* mat2){
    short size1 = getSizeMat(mat1);
    short size2 = getSizeVec(&(*mat1)[0]);
    matrixF* result = new matrixF(size1, vecF(size2));
    vecF* oneVec = new vecF(size2);
    result->clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < size1; i++){
        oneVec->clear();
        for (int j = 0; j < size2; j++){
            oneVec->push_back((*mat1)[i][j] - (*mat2)[i][j]);
        }
        result->push_back(*oneVec);
    }
    return result;
}

vecF* Helpers::subtractVectors(vecF* vec1, vecF* vec2, short size){
    vecF* result = new vecF(size);
    result->clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        result->push_back((*vec1)[i] - (*vec2)[i]);
    }
    return result;
}

matrixF* Helpers::transform(matrixF* input){
    short size1 = getSizeMat(input);
    short size2 = getSizeVec(&(*input)[0]);
    matrixF* result = new matrixF(size2, vecF(size1));
    for (short i = 0; i < size1; i++){
        for (short j = 0; j < size2; j++){
            (*result)[j][i] = (*input)[i][j];
        }
    }
    return result; 
}

matrixF* Helpers::initializeWeight(short size1, short size2, float minNumb, float maxNumb){
    matrixF* weights = new matrixF(size1, vecF(size2));
    for (int i = 0; i < size1; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < size2; j++){
            (*weights)[i][j] = randNumb(minNumb, maxNumb);
        }
    }
    return weights;
}

vecF* Helpers::initializeBias(short size, float minNumb, float maxNumb){
    vecF* bias = new vecF(size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        (*bias)[i] = randNumb(minNumb, maxNumb);
    }
    return bias;
}

void Helpers::checkSizeMatrix(matrixF* input){
    short t = 0, q = 0;      
    for (vecF vec : *input){
        q = 0;
        for (float x : vec){
            q += 1;
        }
        t+=1;
    }
    std::cout<<"Amount vectors: "<<t<<", amount elements each vector: "<<q<<". Quick: ("<<t<<", "<<q<<")"<<std::endl;
}

void Helpers::checkSizeVector(vecF* input){
    short t = 0;      
    for (float f : *input){
        t+=1;
    }
    std::cout<<"Elements: "<<t<<std::endl;
}

void Helpers::getAccuracy(matrixF* output3, matrixF* correctOutput){
    float total = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < batchSize; i++){
        int max1 = std::max_element((*output3)[i].begin(), (*output3)[i].end()) - (*output3)[i].begin();
        int max2 = std::max_element((*correctOutput)[i].begin(), (*correctOutput)[i].end()) - (*correctOutput)[i].begin();
        if (max1 == max2){
            total += 1; 
        }
    }   
    std::cout<<"Accuracy is "<<total/batchSize*100<<"%"<<std::endl;
}

void Helpers::printMatrix(matrixF* input){
    for (vecF vec : *input){
        for (float f : vec){
            std::cout<<f<<", ";
        }
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    }
}

void Helpers::printVector(vecF* input){
    for (float f : *input){
        std::cout<<f<<", ";
    }
    std::cout<<std::endl;
}

void Helpers::checkMemory(bool fullPrint){
        //code by Anderas Masur https://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?280081-Get-available-memory
        MEMORYSTATUS MemStat;
        memset(&MemStat, 0, sizeof(MemStat));
        ::GlobalMemoryStatus(&MemStat);

        if (fullPrint){
            std::cout << "Length of structure: " << MemStat.dwLength
                << std::endl
                << "Memory usage: " << MemStat.dwMemoryLoad
                << " %" << std::endl
                << "Physical memory: " << MemStat.dwTotalPhys / 1024
                << " KB" << std::endl
                << "Free physical memory: " << MemStat.dwAvailPhys / 1024
                << " KB" << std::endl
                << "Paging file: " << MemStat.dwTotalPageFile / 1024
                << " KB" << std::endl
                << "Free paging file: " << MemStat.dwAvailPageFile / 1024
                << " KB" << std::endl
                << "Virtual memory: " << MemStat.dwTotalVirtual / 1024
                << " KB" << std::endl
                << "Free virtual memory: " << MemStat.dwAvailVirtual / 1024
                << " KB" << std::endl;
        } else{
            std::cout<<"Memory usage: "<< MemStat.dwMemoryLoad<<" %"<<std::endl;
        }
    }

void Helpers::checkForNanMatrix(matrixF* input){
    short total = 0;
    for (vecF vec : *input){
        for (float f : vec){
            //Nan compared to something is always false
            if (f != f){
                total+=1;
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout<<"There is "<<total<<" Nan in matrix"<<std::endl;
}

void Helpers::checkForNanVec(vecF* input){
    short total = 0;
    for (float f : *input){
        //Nan compared to something is always false 
        if (f != f){
            total+=1;
        }
    }
    std::cout<<"There is "<<total<<" Nan in vector"<<std::endl;
}
```

```
#ifndef matrixLibrary_h
#define matrixLibrary_h
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <random>
#include <math.h>
#include <numeric>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define batchSize 1000
#define imgSize 748

typedef std::vector<float> vecF;
typedef std::vector<vecF> matrixF;

class Helpers{
public:
    Helpers();
    ~Helpers();

    float randNumb(float minNumb, float maxNumb);

    float reLU(float numb);
    float reLUDeriv(float numb);
    matrixF* reLUMatrix(matrixF* input);

    float sigmoid(float numb);
    float sigmoidDeriv(float numb);
    float sigmoidInverse(float numb);
    matrixF* sigmoidMatrix(matrixF* input);

    float dotProduct(vecF* vector1, vecF* vector2);
    float squareError(vecF* output, vecF* correctOutput, short size);

    matrixF* forwardProp1(matrixF* input, matrixF* weights, vecF* bias, short size);
    matrixF* forwardProp2(matrixF* input, matrixF* weights, vecF* bias, short size1, short size2);
    matrixF* fullDot(matrixF* input1, matrixF* input2, short size1, short size2, float append);
    matrixF* subtractMatrices(matrixF* mat1, matrixF* mat2);
    matrixF* transform(matrixF* input);
    matrixF* initializeWeight(short size1, short size2, float minNumb, float maxNumb);

    vecF* sumMatrix(matrixF* input, float append);    
    vecF* subtractVectors(vecF* vec1, vecF* vec2, short size);
    vecF* initializeBias(short size, float minNumb, float maxNumb);

    short getSizeMat(matrixF* mat);
    short getSizeVec(vecF* vec);

    void outDeriv(matrixF* outMat, matrixF* input1, matrixF* input2, matrixF* input3, short size);
    void addVectors(vecF* vec1, vecF* vec2);
    void addBias(matrixF* input, vecF* bias);

    void checkSizeMatrix(matrixF* input);
    void checkSizeVector(vecF* input);
    void getAccuracy(matrixF* output3, matrixF* correctOutput);
    void printMatrix(matrixF* input);
    void printVector(vecF* input);
    void checkMemory(bool fullPrint);
    void checkForNanMatrix(matrixF* input);
    void checkForNanVec(vecF* input);
};

#include"matrixLibrary.cpp"
#endif
```

Comment: difficult to help without a [mre] but `#include` on a cpp file is suspicious

Comment: By "compiling" (which is generally the same as "building"), do you mean "executing" or "running" your program? If that is the case, use your debugger to see where the code is getting stuck.

Comment: The "matrixLibrary.h" file only needs the `#include <vector>` directive.  None of those other `#include` directives are relevant to that header file, and need not be there (and under the *include what you use* principle, **should not** be there).  `#include"matrixLibrary.cpp"` is highly suspect; if it is all inline functions probably should be called `matrixLibrary.inline.h` or such.

Comment: *My program builds normally, but after a few iterations it just stops compiling.* -- A program "building normally" only means that there are no syntax errors, and the linker is able to find all of the functions you're calling.  It has nothing to do with whether your program has bugs or not.  If all a C++ programmer required is to "build correctly", there wouldn't be any bugs in programs, and you know that isn't the case.

Comment: *I can't figure out why.* -- Debugging is part and parcel of writing programs.  Since you took on the responsibility of getting this library, you should be prepared to debug the program if the program doesn't work correctly.  When you're a programmer, you are no longer the "end user" using an appliance that may be faulty, and then go call customer support about the issue.  The entire responsibility of starting the debugging process is on your shoulders.  *How* to fix the problem is a different story, but at the very least, you need to identify *where* the problem is by debugging your app.

Comment: Is the OOM-killer being invoked?  Are any errors printed when the program exits?

Comment: You might get better attention if you trimmed your code down to a [mre]. Eliminate code that is not needed to reproduce the problem. Do not try to preserve your intended functionality; the only thing you are to preserve is the crash. For example, you have several lines in your main function that appear to be related to performance testing. Get rid of that. Your main function should probably have two lines -- one to define and initialize `mnist` and the other to call `mnist.run()`. Prune mercilessly. Drop calculations, eliminate unused members, etc.